# How to change the Clear Icon in SearchView of Actionbar

Tags: searchview

I used the appcompat to implemented the actionbar, now I want to change the clear icon. And I have done this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search_note"
      android:title="@string/search_title"
      android:orderInCategory="101"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      snailnote:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
      snailnote:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

my team:

```
<item name="searchViewCloseIcon">@drawable/search_clear_normal</item>
```

I also tried to add

```
<item name="android:searchViewCloseIcon">@drawable/search_clear_normal</item>
```

but it is giving an error, and I final removed it.

But it dosen't work, how should I change the clear icon in a right way.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/YourActionBarWidget</item>
</style>

<style name="YourActionBarWidget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="searchViewCloseIcon">@drawable/xxx</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="closeIcon">@drawable/search_clear_normal </item>
</style>
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.